# Car & Two Wheeler Simulator Sound

Tags: sound-design, car

We are a small startup based out of India and are looking at making an ultra low cost but realistic Two wheeler and Car Simulator for Indian villages.

In our attempt, we are looking at providing very realistic engine sounds and program them accordingly to match speed & rpm.

Can you please help us by suggesting the right tool for programming it.

We have our own software platform using DirectX.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because though it's *related* to sound design, it's actually a jobs board/shopping request.

Comment: not any more it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

As far as tools go, you should be looking at WWISE and/or FMOD. This is effectively a game sound exercise and these are possibly the most appropriate tools. UNITY also has a sound engine which can be used independently or with WWISE and/or FMOD.

These tools will work with live audio sounds.

You could also consider attempting synthesis using PureData or MAX/MSP